# How to transmit json data?

Tags: c#, json

I am building a small C# app to get JsonData using a internet.

C# app server has a internet connection.
But our client computer hasn't internet connection they connected with LAN.
Now I have a question. Is it possible to call Json service on server then save and transmit to the client computer?

"server" is part of their LAN. My server had 2 lan. 1 is LAN, 2 is internet.

Here are working code but client users cant use it because they have not internet connection. How to solve this problem? any idea?

```
    public class Namedata
    {
        public string PeopleName { get; set; }
        public string PeopleAge { get; set; }
        public string PeopleSurname { get; set; }
    }
    
    public class SName
    {
        public int ResultCode { get; set; }
        public string ResultName { get; set; }
        public IList<Namedata> namedatas { get; set; }
    }
    
    public class Example
    {
        public SName s_name { get; set; }
    }

  public void GETJsondata()
            {
    string username = "myuser"; 
     string password = "myuserpass";                 
     byte[] byteArray = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("{\"name\":\"" + Name.Text + "\",\"id\":\"1\"}");               
     WebRequest request = WebRequest.Create("http://www.myservice.com/Service4.svc/s_name"); //                
     request.Headers.Add("Authorization", "Basic " + Convert.ToBase64String(Encoding.GetEncoding("ISO-8859-1").GetBytes(username + ":" + password)));
     request.Method = "POST";
     request.ContentType = "application/json";
     request.ContentLength = byteArray.Length;
     Stream stream = request.GetRequestStream();
     stream.Write(byteArray, 0, byteArray.Length);
     stream = request.GetResponse().GetResponseStream();
     var result = (new StreamReader(stream).ReadLine());             
    
    var data = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Example>(result);
ultragridiew1.DataSource = data.s_name.namedatas;
    }
```

Comment: So basically you're asking how you can get your clients to pass data over the internet, without an internet connection? Ehm... you can't...

Comment: @nikneem It reminds me of the time a client asked for a script on their local computer to notify them via e-mail if their Internet went down.

Comment: This question looks almost identical to one posted by another new account earlier today. Please *do not* create duplicate accounts and post the same question again when your question is closed.

Comment: + Your question is attracting close votes because the premise is unclear. You seem to be asking "how do I call a service over the internet without connecting to the internet?". This to most readers is nonsensical, so please *explain* more clearly what the real problem is you are trying to solve.

Comment: I mean is it possible to save data on server then send them to the client? My server is had internet.

Comment: If the client has no internet connection then, unless your "server" is part of their LAN, they cannot send _or_ receive _anything_ from the internet. (It's like asking, when someone has had their phone disconnected, whether you can call them instead of them calling you). Summary: If the two computers you're sending between are in the same LAN, then your code should work. If one of the computers is on the internet, and the LAN is not connected to the internet, then it will never work.

Comment: _"C# app is wcf technology. And wcf server has a internet connection. But our client computer hasn't internet connection they connected with LAN."_ Are Server and Client in the same LAN?

Comment: "server" is part of their LAN. My server had 2 lan. 1 is LAN, 2 is internet.

Comment: @Fildor yes. Server and Client in the same LAN. So I just meant clients can use the service using the server?

Comment: OK, so they share a Network. Good. There's potential. I guess what you want is "server push", which afaik in WCF would need a "[duplex service](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wcf/feature-details/duplex-services?redirectedfrom=MSDN)"

Comment: It sounds like what you really need is a forward proxy on the server which is able to allow a connection to the specific internet endpoint that you're trying to read data from.    However, that's a networking problem rather than a programming problem.

Comment: If I understand your issue, your client try to call the server but cannot resolt the 
`""http://www.myservice.com/Service4.svc/s_name""` because it doesn't know "www.myservice.com" without the help of an internet DNS? 

This look more like a network question. But for now you can change the url to the Lan IP. The answer will be heavy related to the infra you have.

Comment: Yes you are understood my problem.. What does it mean LAN ip?

Comment: By LAN IP I mean "http://192.168.X.Y/", the Ip of the server on the LAN. Get in contact with the network guy he will do the route, configure the proxy etc like https://www.devside.net/archives/wamp-server/accessing-websites-on-a-local-network-lan-web-server (note I don't know your infra! this link is a simpliest listing of possible solution I found for explanation purpuse)

Comment: Doesn't work sir. I have no network guy, How to be routed? please tell me